# Using setProperty() in Apache Camel with an optional value

Tags: apache-camel

This is part of my Camel route. I am using a POST action in Postman and by specifying "filePath" and "mailTo" in the body I am sending an email to whomever I list under mailTo. How would I go about if I wanted to put the mailTo as an optional parameter, i.e user doesn't have to enter this value?

My hopes were that Camel would be so smart as to handle this exception but if I now remove the value in mailTo altogether in the body before sending the POST request it shows a PathNotFoundException. Whereas I want it to be able to run without the mailTo field.

{ "filePath": "whatever", "mailTo": "" } <= this runs the program
{ "filePath": "whatever" } <= this does not run the program

Is there such a feature that can set an optional property?

```
rest(whatever)
    .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
    .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    .consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    .post("/send-email")
        .outType(Email.class)
        .route()
            .setProperty(FILE_PATH, jsonpath("$.filePath"))
            .setProperty(RECIPIENT_LIST, jsonpath("$.mailTo")) // should be optional
            .to(direct(ENTRY_ROUTE))
.endRest();
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle this you could set `suppressExceptions` option of the jsonpath component to be `true`

```
.route()
    .setProperty(FILE_PATH, jsonpath("$.filePath"))
    .setProperty(RECIPIENT_LIST, jsonpath("$.mailTo", true, String.class))
```

Comment: Thanks! But I only get to add two parameters here, and the 2nd one should be resultType. I have another use of this further down where I am declaring setBody().jsonpath("$.mssg"), and here it works fine to add a surpressException-value, which makes me think the issue is in the setParameter-method?

Comment: @Kara there is no problem to provide both arguments at once, I've updated the answer